# facebook call-to-action button for posted item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4, koala-gem

I am posting created product to facebook which is successful....now I want to add `call-to-action` button on that posted product to facebook, something like  `buy now` or `shop now` button.

Did anyone have used `call to action` button with koala gem?

Here is what I am doing to post product to facebook:

```
response = graph.put_connections(self.uid, 'feed', {
  'name' => product.name,
  'link' => "#{ENV['PROTOCOL']}#{ENV['HOSTNAME']}/#{self.id}/timelines",
  'picture' => product_picture_url,
  'description' => product.description
})

product.update_attribute :uid, response['id']
```

Is it possible to add `call-to-action` button for posting product or we can only add `call-to-action` button in ads?

Thanks